# create or get XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: web-part

What I want to do is just same with what I do when I add a list view web parts into a web page. The difference is that I want to do it programmatically.

I know how to import web parts to WebPartsManager and the web parts I have to use is XsltListViewWebPart. But I have no idea about how to create or get it.

Hope someone help me.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this little helper function before:

```
public static XsltListViewWebPart MakeNewXsltListViewWebPart(SPList list, string webPartTitle)
{
    SPView defaultView = list.DefaultView;
    XsltListViewWebPart xsltListViewWebPart = new XsltListViewWebPart();
    xsltListViewWebPart.ID = "wpListView";
    xsltListViewWebPart.Title = webPartTitle;
    xsltListViewWebPart.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
    xsltListViewWebPart.ViewGuid = defaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
    PropertyInfo nodeProp = defaultView.GetType().GetProperty("Node", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    XmlNode node = nodeProp.GetValue(defaultView, null) as XmlNode;
    XmlNode toolbarNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Toolbar");
    if (toolbarNode != null)
    {
        if (!toolbarNode.Attributes["Type"].Value.Equals("Freeform"))
        {
            toolbarNode.Attributes["Type"].Value = "Freeform";
         }
    }

    defaultView.Update();
    return xsltListViewWebPart;
}
```

You will want to customize some of the webpart's properties for your needs (ChromeType, AllowEdit, etc.)

Then to add it to a page, you can use LimitedWebPartManager on a webpart page :

```
Guid storageKey = Guid.Empty;
using (var manager = item.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    var webPart = WebPartHelper.CreateWebPart(web, webPartName, manager);

    if (webPart != null)
    {
        manager.AddWebPart(webPart, webPartZoneName, webPartZoneIndex);
        storageKey = manager.GetStorageKey(webPart);
        webPart.Dispose();
    }
}
```