# Set a view of a list in XsltListViewWebPart when deploying from VS2012 to SP2013 App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app

I am devloping a SP2013 App which includes a page (aspx) that contains the following webpart and XsltListViewWebPart as shown below.  I have managed to remove all the elements i want to remove (Toolbar, seaarchbox etc) but I want to specify the view (I have created 4 views for the list) that the list default to but I can see any option to do this?

Anyone achived this?

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="HolidayBalance" Title="loc:HolidayBalance" PartChromeType="TitleOnly" ShowTitleIcons="True" AllowLayoutChange="False">
        <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListYourHolidayBalance" runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/Personnel Holiday Entitlement"  IsIncluded="True" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="Your Holiday Balance" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" Default="True" DisableViewSelectorMenu="True" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ShowToolbarWithRibbon="False" >
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you plan to provision the page using a Module, I'd recommend configuring the web part inside of the Module, rather than in the aspx file itself. This will allow you to select whichever view you would want:

```
<File Path="mypage.aspx" Url="mypage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
  <View List="Lists/Personnel Holiday Entitlement" BaseViewID="4" WebPartZoneID="HolidayBalance" WebPartOrder="1">
    <![CDATA[
          <webParts>
              <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                  <metaData>
                      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                  </metaData>
                  <data>
                      <properties>
                          <property name="Title" type="string">Your Holiday Balance</property>
                          <property name="DisableViewSelectorMenu" type="bool">True</property>
                          <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
                          <property name="ShowToolbarWithRibbon" type="bool">False</property>
                      </properties>
                  </data>
              </webPart>
          </webParts>
      ]]>
  </View>
</File>
```

Note: this example is from SP 2010, hopefully it's applicable and compatible with SP 2013.

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks for that, have just arrive at the same conclusion!  Slightly annoying that my VS intelisense does not seem to work inside <![CDATA[ but at least i can do what i need to do.

Comment: I should have listened, found this a week ago.  I changed Version to 15.0.0.0 for SP2013.  I also used this http://blog.ozippy.com/2011/04/creating-views-in-list-definition-using.html to provision my view correctly and changed the BaseViewID to match.  Perfect thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it pro-grammatically check this link out. Where they getting the webpart and then setting it's view.

[create or get XsltListViewWebPart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36581/create-or-get-xsltlistviewwebpart)

You can change default view in the definition of your list too.

Here's a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37480/defining-custom-views-in-a-lists-schema-xml-file) on SE that explains how to change list's default view in Schema.xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply...yes I have seen this but I am displaying the list twice on the same page...for 1 list I want to show the default view (all) and in the other list a custom view...Does this mean i need to create two lists containing the exact same content?!

Comment: I see, since you will have 2 webparts and I assume with different titles, then pro-grammatical approach should work as get each webpart using there title.

Comment: Yip i have two different web parts, its seems crazy i can specify the view in the tags for the XsltListViewWebPart.